# React router changes url but not the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I click on the Navigation links the URL changes but the component doesn't  render, and when I reload the page with the same link the component renders

**APP.js**

```
render() {
         return (
           <div>
             <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Main}  />
                  <Route path="/Men"component={DisplayPage} />
                </Switch>       
            </BrowserRouter>
          </div>
        )
    }
```

Nav.js

```
return (
      <div className="MainContainer">
        <header>
        
        <nav>
          <ul>
        
          <li><Title/></li>    
          <li><Link to='/Men'>MEN</Link></li>
          <li><a href>WOMEN</a></li>
          <li><a href>STYLEGUIDE</a></li>
          <li><a href>OUTLET</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      <Cart/>
   </header>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Can you share the working code for the same?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360520/react-js-router-changes-url-but-not-loading-page

Comment: I guess the problem I am facing is different from the link you provided

Comment: Share Main and DisplayPage component too...

Answer (score 0):

Add the Nav component inside `<BrowserRouter>`:

```
return (
         <div>
           <BrowserRouter>
             <Nav />
             <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Main}  />
               <Route path="/Men"component={DisplayPage} />
              </Switch>    
           </BrowserRouter>
         </div>
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try like this ?

```
render() {
         return (
             <BrowserRouter>
              <Nav />
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Main}  />
                  <Route exact path="/Men"component={DisplayPage} />
                </Switch>       
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Its working now..Is there any reason why it was not working before

Comment: The error probably occurred because you returned it in a div. No need to use Div. and it will work with the exact parameter when the full address is provided.

Comment: if the problem is resolved, mark it as resolved so that other users can take advantage.

Comment: I'm not talking about writing the post as resolved, I'm talking about marking my answer as resolved :)

Comment: @CanUver your answer is exact same as of mine, you should check answers first before posting yours.